# css, swf and skins mxml files location in FLex Project

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4, flash, skins

I have a FLex 4 project.

Its becoming cumbersome due to all css, swf and skins mxml files put in ONE folder. I want to separate css in a css folder and under the skins folder, I want to have the swf folder and the skins mxml files will be put in the root of the skin folder itself.

I want to know if this is the right way to handle files location. Because as it is in the css file, I now have to specify the path to the swf as for example...  /skins/myswf.swf

So I also want to know if this will have any performance issue at runtime of the interfaces?

Thanks to guide me to the most appropriate way.

Comment: How are you compiling your project? Flash Builder?

Comment: I don't understand why your skins are in their own swf.  You should take a screenshot of your directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that creating a separate library project to store all of your theme is the best. This way you can have multiple applications reference the same styles and skins. It also forces you to organize your code, which can sometimes be daunting.

This is also especially useful for using the same theme across platforms, for example... imagine a mobile app, a native app, and a web app that all use the same styles, pretty sweet right??

See my attached screenshot of an example workspace.. and there is a ton of info out on the interwebs about creating a flex library project.

[image: theme library project]

Comment: you should post some links as well that explain this concept in further detail